# permission denied when activating virtual environment

Tags: permissions, sudo

When typing from local user the following command: 'source .env/bin/activate' returns 'bash: .env/bin/activate: Permission denied'

I can 'sudo bash' and then 'source .env/bin/activate' and that works fine, but I want it to do it from my user, not from root. How can that be fixed?

Comment: i found the following solution 'sudo chonw -R user:user '/path/to/venv', but somewhere read that might be problematic, I do not know why that may cause a problem